# Why are the getters on Exception final?

Tags: php, exception, subclass

I'm extending the `Exception` class and in my subclass I want to override the `getMessage` method to do some message specific formatting for this particular exception. However, according to the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.extending.php) all the getters in the `Exception` class are `final`.

What is the rational behind the idea that the getters of the `Exception` class must be `final`?

Answer (score 1):

The reason it's `final` is that you want this rather important class to always have the same implementation of the core functions. So if someone comes behind you they can still use `getMessage()`. This is the whole idea behind `final`, that no child can overwrite the parent.

Just write your own method

```
class MyException extends Exception {

      public function getMyErrors() {
           return $this->message;
      }
}
```